# Kafka org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException for some of the records

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, azure-eventhub

Getting below error message when producing record to Azure event hub(kafka enabled)

```
Expiring 14 record(s) for eventhubname: 30125  ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

Stack used azure eventhub , Spring kafka

below config present in Kafka producer config

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "3");
```

Would like to know if kafka producer will be retried 3 times incase of above error message

Comment: The default retries already is `2147483647`, so if you don't currently see it retrying, then, no this wont help

Comment: @OneCricketeer would like to know if retry is triggered incase of above error?

Comment: If you've not set the retries config, then it's already set to retry and you should see logs that it is retrying or not

Comment: @OneCricketeer  have set this props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "3");  but would like to know whether  "Expiring 14 record(s) for eventhubname: 30125  ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
" this exception is eligible for retry org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException

Comment: Yes, I read the question that says the same thing. I'm telling you that setting the producer config on your own is irrelevant since it's already set by default to a higher number. Therefore, if you currently see no retires, then that exception is not eligible. You can read the Kafka Javadoc to see which exceptions will have retries

Answer (score 0):

ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG -> This configuration has no use.
Default retry is set as Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647.

Producer automatically retry in case of failure.

Kindly check following configuration and tune accordingly.

- linger.ms=0 ( try with zero, this will send batch request as soon as possible, Non zero value require more tuning along with other parameters)
- buffer.memory -> Max memory used by Producer in buffer, try increasing this.
- max.block.ms -> check this value, This is probable cause of timeoutException. Increase this as per scenario.